# beginner python user: trouble with error code - too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, validation

This program is meant to receive a username and password and validate them. I'm only looking at the username part for now.

This is my function:

```
def valid_username(username):
    if not username.isalpha():
        reason = ('username can only contain alpha numeric numbers')
        return reason

    numupper =0
    for c in username:
        if not c.isupper():
            numupper = numupper + 1

        if numupper <= 0:
            reason=('username must contain at least one uppercase character')
            return reason

    numlower =0
    for c in username:
        if not c.islower():
            numlower = numlower + 1

        if numlower <= 0:
            reason=('username must contain at least one lowercase character')
            return reason

        if len(username)<8:
            reason = ('username must be greater than 8 characters')
            return reason

    numdigit=0
    for c in username:
        if not c.isdigit():
            numdigit = numdigit + 1

        if numdigit <= 0:
            reason= ('username must contain at least one number')
            return reason
```

and this is my program:

```
import uservalidation

# get a username from the user
username = input("Username: ")

# validate username
result, reason = uservalidation.valid_username(username)

# if it isn't valid we should tell them why
if not(result):
    print (reason)

(the next else is the password part)
```

but I'm getting this error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/katiemoore/Documents/MooreKatie_assign9.py", line 7, in <module>
    result, reason = uservalidation.valid_username(username)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I don't really know what that means, can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

The function `valid_username` return only one string `reason`. But you receive two arguments at the function call. Hence the error. So, It would be appropriate to return a null string as to be assigned to the `result` variable will be correct

instead of

```
return reason
```

use

```
return '',reason
```

Which will work

Answer (score 0):

The solution Aswin Murugesh offered is correct, although in some use cases `return None,reason` might be more appropriate. But I think the explanation could be usefully expanded.

This syntax tells Python that whatever `uservalidation.valid_username` returns, it should have exactly two elements, and that the first should be assigned to the name `result` and the second to the name `reason`:

```
result, reason = uservalidation.valid_username(username)
```

This isn't specific to function calls - you can use that unpacking syntax with anything. EG:

```
>>> result, reason = ('foo', 'bar')
>>> result
'foo'
>>> reason
'bar'
```

Unpacking like this will raise an exception if the number of values is incorrect. Your function `valid_username` only returns a single value:

```
return reason
```

Normally, unpacking will tell you if the number of elements that you're trying to unpack is too low:

```
>>> result, reason = ('foo',)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    result, reason = ('foo',)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Or if the object you're trying to unpack can't be unpacked at all:

```
>>> result, reason = 7

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    result, reason = 7
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

However, you're returning a single string. Strings can be sliced and indexed as a sequence of characters, and therefore can be unpacked.

```
>>> result, reason = 'foobar'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
    result, reason = 'foobar'
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

In this case, the unpacking syntax interprets `foobar` as a six-element sequence. Because I've only asked for the first two values, it raise an exception reporting that it has more values than it can assign.

Just for comparison:

```
>>> result, reason = 'ab'
>>> result
'a'
>>> reason
'b'

>>> result, reason = 'a'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
    result, reason = 'a'
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

So you need to make sure that your attempt to unpack the return value of your function matches what your function returns. I'm not sure where `result` is supposed to come from in your function, but you should either calculate and return it, return a placeholder like `None` as part of a tuple, or change your assignment of the return value of the function.

You don't have to use unpacking to handle the return value - if you specify a single variable name, that variable will be assigned the return value of the function regardless of whether it's a single object or a tuple. Again, this is nothing special about function return values - it's the same behavior as:

```
>>> foo = 7
>>> bar = (7, 8)
```

This can be useful when you don't know the number of elements a call will return. EG:

```
>>> foo = 'foo,foo'.split(',')
>>> bar = 'bar,bar,bar'.split(',')
>>> len(foo)
2
>>> len(bar)
3
```

The bottom line is that if you want to use the unpacking syntax to accept multiple return values from a function, you need to make sure that function always returns the exact number of values.